# Program crashes when I compile, run and enter the integer value for variable "c"

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, dev-c++

When I run this program in Dev C++, it executes until it prompts to input the integer value of variable 'c'. Then, I input the value, and the whole program crashes. There is no syntax error; the thing is it runs fine when I do not use the If(Condition) statement.

[The following image shows how the output looks like when I compile and run the program.][1]

```c
// Program to display patterns of numbers according to the input values
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int i, j, in, ni, jn, nj, c;
  printf("For the statements for(i=ni;i<=/>=in;i++/--) and\n");
  printf("For(j=nj;j<=/>=jn;j++/--),\n");
  printf("\nEnter ni: ");
  scanf("%d", &ni);
  printf("\nEnter in: ");
  scanf("%d", &in);
  printf("\nEnter nj: ");
  scanf("%d", &nj);
  printf("\nEnter jn: ");
  scanf("%d", &jn);
  printf("\nSelect your choice for the type of for loop to be used:\n");
  printf("\n01. for(i=ni;i<=in;i++) & for(j=nj;j<=jn;j++)\n");
  printf("\n02. for(i=ni;i<=in;i++) & for(j=nj;j<=jn;j--)\n");
  printf("\n03. for(i=ni;i<=in;i++) & for(j=nj;j>=jn;j--)\n");
  printf("\n04. for(i=ni;i<=in;i++) & for(j=nj;j>=jn;j++)\n");
  printf("\n05. for(i=ni;i<=in;i--) & for(j=nj;j<=jn;j++)\n");
  printf("\n06. for(i=ni;i<=in;i--) & for(j=nj;j<=jn;j--)\n");
  printf("\n07. for(i=ni;i<=in;i--) & for(j=nj;j>=jn;j--)\n");
  printf("\n08. for(i=ni;i<=in;i--) & for(j=nj;j>=jn;j++)\n");
  printf("\n09. for(i=ni;i>=in;i++) & for(j=nj;j<=jn;j++)\n");
  printf("\n10. for(i=ni;i>=in;i++) & for(j=nj;j<=jn;j--)\n");
  printf("\n11. for(i=ni;i>=in;i++) & for(j=nj;j>=jn;j--)\n");
  printf("\n12. for(i=ni;i>=in;i++) & for(j=nj;j>=jn;j++)\n");
  printf("\n13. for(i=ni;i>=in;i--) & for(j=nj;j<=jn;j++)\n");
  printf("\n14. for(i=ni;i>=in;i--) & for(j=nj;j<=jn;j--)\n");
  printf("\n15. for(i=ni;i>=in;i--) & for(j=nj;j>=jn;j--)\n");
  printf("\n16. for(i=ni;i>=in;i--) & for(j=nj;j>=jn;j++)\n");
  printf(
      "\nInput must be between 1 and 16 inclusive(Including 1 and 16 too)\n");
  scanf("%d", &c);
  if (c == 1) {
    for (i = ni; i <= in; i++) {
      for (j = nj; j <= jn; j++) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c == 2) {
    for (i = ni; i <= in; i++) {
      for (j = nj; j <= jn; j--) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c == 3) {
    for (i = ni; i <= in; i++) {
      for (j = nj; j >= jn; j--) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c == 4) {
    for (i = ni; i <= in; i++) {
      for (j = nj; j >= jn; j++) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c == 5) {
    for (i = ni; i <= in; i--) {
      for (j = nj; j <= jn; j++) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c == 6) {
    for (i = ni; i <= in; i--) {
      for (j = nj; j <= jn; j--) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c == 7) {
    for (i = ni; i <= in; i--) {
      for (j = nj; j >= jn; j--) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c == 8) {
    for (i = ni; i <= in; i--) {
      for (j = nj; j >= jn; j++) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c == 9) {
    for (i = ni; i >= in; i++) {
      for (j = nj; j <= jn; j++) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c = 10) {
    for (i = ni; i >= in; i++) {
      for (j = nj; j <= jn; j--) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c = 11) {
    for (i = ni; i >= in; i++) {
      for (j = nj; j >= jn; j--) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c = 12) {
    for (i = ni; i >= in; i++) {
      for (j = nj; j >= jn; j++) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c = 13) {
    for (i = ni; i >= in; i--) {
      for (j = nj; j <= jn; j++) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c = 14) {
    for (i = ni; i >= in; i--) {
      for (j = nj; j <= jn; j--) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c = 15) {
    for (i = ni; i >= in; i--) {
      for (j = nj; j >= jn; j--) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c = 16) {
    for (i = ni; i >= in; i--) {
      for (j = nj; j >= jn; j++) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else if (c < 1 || c > 16) {
    printf("Invalid choice input. Please enter numbers between 1 and 16 only.");
  }
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: you need to pass a pointer to c ( &c) to scanf

Comment: This doesn't look valid: `printf("For(j=nj;j<=/>=jn;j++/--),\n");`

Comment: @BillLynch I guess it's time for me to go to sleep :)

Comment: `if(c=10)` really

Comment: Welcome so SO. Please take a look at [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code is very long compared with what would be needed to demonstrate the problem. You could (and should) easily remove most of your `if` and `printf` instructions. If you want people to help, don't make them wade through loads of code that does not add any value.

Comment: And as a general rule: Before you run your code, compile with maximum warnings and read all of them. Only after you have solved or at least understood them you should run your program. If there are warnings left, running the program will likely be a waste of time.

Comment: You must understand arguments and parameters.  Essentially, 'foo(x)' cannot mutate the x argument because it is COPIED into the parameter that foo is supplied with.  I cannot understand how you got all the other scanf's right and the one for c wrong without spotting the bug straightaway?

Answer (score 2):

It likely has to do with all the warnings that your compiler should be emiting.

```
<source>:34:16: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%d",c);
           ~~  ^
<source>:134:18: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
        else if(c=10)
                ~^~~
<source>:134:18: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
        else if(c=10)
                 ^
                (   )
<source>:134:18: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
        else if(c=10)
                 ^
                 ==
<source>:145:18: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
        else if(c=11)
                ~^~~
<source>:145:18: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
        else if(c=11)
                 ^
                (   )
<source>:145:18: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
        else if(c=11)
                 ^
                 ==
<source>:156:18: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
        else if(c=12)
                ~^~~
<source>:156:18: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
        else if(c=12)
                 ^
                (   )
<source>:156:18: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
        else if(c=12)
                 ^
                 ==
<source>:167:18: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
        else if(c=13)
                ~^~~
<source>:167:18: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
        else if(c=13)
                 ^
                (   )
<source>:167:18: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
        else if(c=13)
                 ^
                 ==
<source>:178:18: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
        else if(c=14)
                ~^~~
<source>:178:18: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
        else if(c=14)
                 ^
                (   )
<source>:178:18: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
        else if(c=14)
                 ^
                 ==
<source>:189:18: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
        else if(c=15)
                ~^~~
<source>:189:18: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
        else if(c=15)
                 ^
                (   )
<source>:189:18: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
        else if(c=15)
                 ^
                 ==
<source>:200:18: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
        else if(c=16)
                ~^~~
<source>:200:18: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
        else if(c=16)
                 ^
                (   )
<source>:200:18: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
        else if(c=16)
                 ^
                 ==
<source>:34:16: warning: variable 'c' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    scanf("%d",c);
               ^
<source>:5:26: note: initialize the variable 'c' to silence this warning
    int i,j,in,ni,jn,nj,c;
                         ^
                          = 0
9 warnings generated.
```

Comment: Only the first warning is relevant to the segmentation fault.